# automatically access default browser by os and copy the value from input field to my program

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests

i've created electron app that will asking for authorization to my google drive account. my application is very simple, it will display the list of files from my google drive account. [Here's the link](https://github.com/dhanyn10/electron-example/tree/master/gdrive)
To get the authorization key, **manually** i have to click authorize button from my electron app, then it will open new tab in my default browser. i need to give the permission to accessing my google drive data. Then google drive will provide the authorization key to me then i can get and enter the key to my app.

How do I run the above scenario **automatically**?

Answer (score 1):

You *really* don't want this to be the default flow for your users' code so I am assuming you are asking for test automation so you can test this works. You would basically:

- Install the `chromedriver` package.
- You would create a script that downloads and launches chromedriver then use something like [webdriver.io](https://webdriver.io/) to launch a Chrome session.
- In the session, you would [configure](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/674#issuecomment-403625792) the user data directory to the user's real directory. You can find the locations in different operating systems [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md#:%7E:text=The%20default%20location%20is%20in,%25%5CGoogle%5CChrome%5CUser%20Data).
- You now have a fully automated Chrome with the user's data.
- Now, you use electron to request permissions, which will open a tab on the browser with an active selenium session.
- Call `browser.click('...')` on whatever element you want in the page to accept the request.

---

I want to make it very clear this is *only* acceptable and will work when testing. "In the wild" controlling the user's browser without explicit permission through a third-party executable is a sure-fire way to get flagged by every anti-malware product in the market and liable for data breaches.